# Integration by parts with 2 variables

Tags: calculus, integration

I know that I can apply Integration by Parts to derive:

$$\int udv=uv-\int vdu$$

I've been trying to derive the following but I'm slightly confused as to how the below was derived:

$$\int_{k}^{\infty}(x-k)\frac{d^{j}g}{dx^{j}}(x)dx=\frac{d^{j-2}g}{dx^{j-2}}(k)$$

Does anyone have any ideas? Slightly confused as well on why $g(x)$ was replaced with $g(k)$.

Comment: What is the relation between $j$ and $m$?

Comment: One would require $\frac{d^j g}{dx^j}$ to decay sufficiently quickly for the integral to exist. Regarding your confusion, $x$ is a dummy variable which is integrated out. The RHS cannot depend on $x$.

Comment: @geetha290krm heya apologies - it was a typo. Just corrected it.

Comment: Take $u=x-k, v=\frac {d^{j-1}g} {dx^{j-1}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u = x - k$ and $dv = \frac{d^{j} g}{d x^{j}}$ then
\begin{align}
\int (x-k) \, \frac{d^{j}g}{dx^{j}}(x)dx &= (x-k) \, \frac{d^{j-1} g}{d x^{j-1}} - \int \frac{d^{j-1} g}{d x^{j-1}} \, dx \\
&= \int \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{d^{j-2} g}{d x^{j-2}} \right) \, dx \\
&= \frac{d^{j-2} g}{d x^{j-2}}.
\end{align}
Taking the desired limits yields the result.